# React.js app is removing whitespace in strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to format some text in a React app, and for some reason, the whitespace is getting removed. For example, if I have I class with the render method

```
render() {

    return (<div>
               <div>{"average time: " + 5}</div>
               <div>{"best    time: " + 1}</div>             
            </div>);
}
```

then the rendered output removes the spaces I have in the second line, yielding an output that looks like

```
average time: 5
best time: 1
```

However, I want the output to look like

```
average time: 5
best    time: 1
```

How do I achieve that?

Elsewhere, I read that adding a `className` with `display: block` would fix this, but that did not help. Specifically, I tried this:

```
render() {

    return (<div>
               <div className="stats_entry">{"average time: " + 5}</div>
               <div className="stats_entry">{"best    time: " + 1}</div>             
            </div>);
}
```

where the css file has

```
.stats_entry {
  display: block;
}
```

EDIT:

Per suggestion, I tried changing the css to

```
.stats_entry {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

but this did not fix the issue.

EDIT:

wrapping the text with `pre` solved the issue:

```
render() {

    return (<div>
               <div><pre>{"average time: " + 5}</pre></div>
               <div><pre>{"best    time: " + 1}</pre></div>             
            </div>);
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with **React**, it's basic **HTML**

Comment: Ok. What is the solution?

Comment: I did google, as I said in the original question.

Comment: Then why don't you use `&nbsp;` if you did Google as you say?

Comment: Because I did not realize this was an html issue.

Comment: In the future if you come across a weird scenario, try to reproduce it in the most simple env possible (HTML, CSS) and then gradually make things more complex, or the other way, start with what you have and then start to remove things until you focus on the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should use white-space: pre; in your css

Comment: This did not fix the issue.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer. it's also not the correct answer since it does not explain why this is happening and how to properly solve it without hacks.

Comment: idk why @vsync is mad at this answer, this is exactly what I use StackOverflow for, quick solutions to my silly problems. Anyway, this was precisely what I needed.